# Can a UIView be fixed in place during a segue transition?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

I am creating a board game where each board piece is an instance of a view controller.  I have subclassed UIStoryboardSegue so that each piece smoothly flows from one to the other.  However, my game piece stays centered in this frame during the transition.  I would like to have it so that my gamePiece (a UIImageView) stays in the center of the screen throughout the entire transition, but haven't had any luck searching.

Here is my Segue subclass, if it helps at all:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class RightToLeftSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        let src: UIViewController = self.sourceViewController 
        let dst: UIViewController = self.destinationViewController 
        let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
        let timeFunc : CAMediaTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        transition.duration = 1.25
        transition.timingFunction = timeFunc
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
        src.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        src.navigationController!.pushViewController(dst, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this UIImageView to the window as subview before the transition happens.This way you will have it throughout the transition.
Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: This lets the piece stay still during the transition, which is awesome and what I asked for. Now, is there any way of hiding the imageView on the view controller while I have the imageView added to the window?

Comment: In the viewWillAppear of destination hide the imageview. And once its view did appear is called, show it and then hide the one from the window.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much!